# Maximum Concurrent C++ Compilations VS Maximum Number Of Parallel Project Builds

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cpu, cpu-usage

I noticed earlier that when my VS is building my big c++ solution, my CPU usage was less than 25%. Wondering if I can set VS to always use 100% CPU, I did some [**research**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974304/c-how-to-limit-visual-studios-multi-processor-compilation):

Found two options that can be configured for this purpose:

- Maximum Number Of Parallel Project Builds

[image]

- Maximum Concurrent C++ Compilations

[image]

What is the difference?

And to achieve my goal, bonus question is how can I set VS to use more CPU when it builds?

Comment: The first setting is about projects. The second setting is about individual translation units.

Comment: @drescherjm So if I set 12 projects, and 4 compilations, will it build 12 projects at the same time, 4 files per project? Total of 4x12 files

Comment: BTW, things have improved over the years however I still have long periods of building that has the CPU no where near 100%. However I believe a lot of this is related to moc (buinding c++ Qt projects).

Comment: ***So I set 12 projects, and 4 compilations, will it build 4 files per project and 12 projects at the same time, total of 4x12 files simultaneously?*** I don't think you want to change the second setting. I believe 0 means unlimited.

Comment: To increase parallelism in your build, step one is to try to reduce dependencies between your modules. There's no "magic" setting that can do that for you, just hard work/refactoring.

Comment: I fully agree with that. Dependencies between projects cause the first setting to not be used to its maximum.

Comment: @drescherjm "I believe a lot of this is related to moc " - with a sufficiently recent Qt (using 5.11.1 here) and a sufficiently recent cmake (3.11.2+) and a sufficiently recent ninja, you can get moc to run in parallel with the rest of your build quite nicely (modulo hard dependencies on the output of course).

Comment: I am using CMake but have not tried ninja yet.

Comment: @drescherjm You should. It blows both msbuild and make out of the water. Especially versions from within the last 6-8 months.

Comment: @drescherjm : be sure to use [AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) in your CMakeLists.text files with cmake 3.11.2 and newer (they made some very nice parallelism improvements in 3.11 and 3.11.2 fixed some annoying bugs in that regard).

Comment: Thanks. I don't think we should further the discussion on this point since we may be drifting off topic of the question. @SandraK did not mention Qt.

Comment: @SandraK for code to solve problem posed in your ( deleted ) question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52046650/16582 please see https://ideone.com/hst1zw

Comment: @ravenspoint Guardian angel ! Got it, would you like me to reopen the question and post the answer? I am fine both ways

Comment: @SandraK I don't know why you closed it, just as as I was finishing the code.  So, your call.

Comment: @ravenspoint It seems like I have not tried anything and will get closed/down voted. I reopened now. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can often be insightful to see all the files considered in a build. It's not uncommon to access 10.000 files, especially when using bigger libraries.

The fastest way to access these files would be if they're in RAM already, i.e. the OS file cache. Otherwise, an SSD is a reasonable alternative. But if they have to come from a mechanical HDD, the CPU will spend a large amount of time just sleeping while it waits for files to be read.

Hence, the way to improve CPU utilization is to make sure it's not waiting for I/O. Hardware is much cheaper than C++ programmers; get a fast SSD and sufficient RAM.

Comment: I never thought of that! Thank you