# How to determine nodes based on distances matrix?

Tags: c++, graph

Say I have a given of:

> A -> B **10**
>
> A -> C **5**
>
> A -> D **7.5**
>
> B -> C **12**
>
> B -> D **17**
>
> C -> D **5**

Then, I receive an unsorted input, something like below:

```
    K   L   M   N
K   0   10  12  17
L   10  0   5  7.5
M   12  5   0   5
N   17  7.5 5   0
```

I have to determine(for any sort of input - of any order) which node (K, L, M & N) is actually the A, the B, the C and the D.

For the above example input, the case here is that `A is L`, `B is K`, `C is M` & `D is N`.

So I have started something, but I am still not sure how to continue. The below provides me with a std::map of which row of the input, is the row of the given. But then, I am not sure how to know the unknown (order of cities) even when I know that combination exists. Can someone help me sort the input to match the given?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

bool checkForSimilar(vector<double> Vec1, vector<double> Vec2)
{
   std::sort(Vec1.begin(), Vec1.end());
   std::sort(Vec2.begin(), Vec2.end());

   return std::equal(Vec1.begin(), Vec1.end(), Vec1.begin(), Vec2.end());
}

int main()
{
   vector<vector<double>> GivenDistances = {  // A   B   C   D
                                          /*A*/ {0,  10, 5,  7.5},
                                          /*B*/ {10, 0,  12, 17 },
                                          /*C*/ {5,  12, 0,  5  },
                                          /*D*/ {7.5,17, 5,  0  }};

   vector<vector<double>> InputDistances = {  // K   L   M   N
                                          /*K*/{ 0,  10, 12, 17 },
                                          /*L*/{ 10, 0,  5,  7.5},
                                          /*M*/{ 12, 5,  0,  5  },
                                          /*N*/{ 17, 7.5,5,  0  }};

   std::map<int, int> RowMatches;
   for (int i = 0; i < InputDistances.size(); i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < InputDistances[i].size(); j++)
      {
         // check if current row is any combination if GivenDistances
         if (checkForSimilar(InputDistances[i], GivenDistances[j]))
         {
            RowMatches[i] = j;
         }
      }
   }

   // How to order then them??


   int pause; 
   cin >> pause;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I would guess because you asked a asked 'please help' kind of question not specific question on a particular point of C++. Doesn't bother me but I think it bothers some.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake by only looking row by row. There is no way to tell {5,0,0,5} from {0,5,5,0} since they both sort to {5,5,0,0}. You need to include the column information in there somewhere. Sorting the rows is only a start.

Comment: @user4581301 I am sorting a copy of the vector, so columns are preserved in their original form, not sure how to take advantage of sorting and having columns input, to then get my desired output

Comment: @john I see your point, I am trying and got lost. Not sure how to tackle this

Comment: You're really supposed to figure this out by doing research and writing down a strategy on paper first. 
 Jumping into writing code without a firm plan is not the way to go about this.

Comment: Optimization note: You will want to memoize the sorted rows (and probably columns) so that you don't have to sort over and over again. I think you could solve this by brute-force comparing permutations, since each row mirrors a column there won't be many permutations, but this won't be particularly fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function to solve the problem:

```
    /** Solve problem posed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/52046650/16582

    Search for a permuted column in the input matrix
    which matches each given column

    @param[out] assign  the first node assignment which creates a match
    @param[in]  distance  the distances between nodes, given and input

    Mean time to find match ( milliseconds )

    <pre>
    Cities      Search1      Search2
    10            20           0.01
    100           ???          4
    </pre2>

    */

void Find(
    cNodeAssign& assign,
    cNodeDistance& distance )
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch R("Search");

    assign.Clear();

    // loop over rows in given distances
    for( int given = 0; given < distance.Size(); given++ )
    {
        // loop over rows in input distances
        for( int input = 0; input < distance.Size(); input++ )
        {
            // check if the input row has already been assigned
            if( assign.Find( input ) )
                continue;

            // check if row and column are permutations of each other
            if( distance.IsPermutation( given, input ))
            {
                // found a match
                assign.Add( input );

                // no need to search further for this row
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main code to demo the function and perform time profiling

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Original Problem:\n";
    vector<vector<double>> GivenDistances =    // A   B   C   D
    {
        /*A*/ {0,  10, 5,  7.5},
        /*B*/ {10, 0,  12, 17 },
        /*C*/ {5,  12, 0,  5  },
        /*D*/ {7.5,17, 5,  0  }
    };

    vector<vector<double>> InputDistances =    // K   L   M   N
    {
        /*K*/{ 0,  10, 12, 17 },
        /*L*/{ 10, 0,  5,  7.5},
        /*M*/{ 12, 5,  0,  5  },
        /*N*/{ 17, 7.5,5,  0  }
    };

    cNodeDistance dop( GivenDistances, InputDistances );
    cNodeAssign assign( dop.Size() );

    dop.Display();
    Find( assign, dop );
    assign.Display();

    Demo( 4 );

    Demo( 10 );

    Timer( 10 );

    Timer( 100 );
}
```

The code to build the demo application is [available here](https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/f0d526572241d72af204fa2e776b8612).