# How to reduce Visual Studio build process priority to prevent unresponsive system?

Tags: visual-studio

We are compiling big C++ projects using Visual Studio (2013) on a regular basis. Building the source can take up to 45 mins on a developer machine.
During this time, the machine often becomes unresponsive due to 100% CPU load.
Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to run the compile/build tools with a lower process priority so that the Windows UI isn't slowed down?
I'd happily have the machine spend a bit more time overall on the build process if i could do other things meanwhile.

The problem has even become more annoying since installing an SSD!
Although the overall build time is significantly improved, now that there is no more disk bottleneck, the build process runs into CPU max load even more often, with an unresponsive system as a consequence.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: A CI server and a sensible build strategy could probably go a long way.  A better desktop machine couldn't hurt either, if yours is also 2013 vintage.

Comment: To clarify about your build strategy: break your program into logical modules (i.e. DLL's), and only build the ones you're working on.

Comment: The 45 mins are for a complete build only of course. We do have breakdown in modules and have reduced build times for changes limited to those. I'm still interested in having my system responsive during these shorter times.

Comment: Complete builds should be done on a CI server.

Comment: We have a CI server for our Release builds. I'm talking about Debug builds on developer machines here.
For what it is worth, i have been using the option /maxcpucount:3 on a command line build with msbuild.exe to limit build to 3 cores on a quadcore system with some limited success.
But there are still long times where the system is at 100% (and unresponsive).
Ideally, I'd like my system to run at 100% during build, but with lower than normal priority so as to be still be RESPONSIVE.

Comment: VS uses parallel builds by default, you might want to hamper it a bit.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.  Do keep in mind that your OS does not have a good reason to make your UI sluggish.  You are likely to have another issue, anti-malware is always on the top of that list.  The crapware does not deal well with executable files appearing from seemingly nowhere.

Comment: And virus scanners.

Comment: Yeah, anti-virus/-malware, good point. We have those and they're running constantly with high CPU loads on every disk access.

Comment: Report the bug to VS team (i did a few times already). I'm not sure how they themselves use it in large projects with these issues

Answer (score 41):

### Update

I've just found the following thread, where someone by the name of Mikhail Virovets provided an automatic solution: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/436208/limit-cpu-usage-of-visual-studio.html

In the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\cl.exe\PerfOptions`, create a `DWORD` value called `CpuPriorityClass` and set it to `5`. This will set the base priority of *all* newly created processes with that name to `below normal`. You should probably also create a similar entry for the linker.

Of course this is a little bit more invasive as it will affect all processes with those names, regardless of where, when and how they are created. But I think it will probably work fine.

Just don't forget you have added those values in case it causes some unwanted slowdowns in the future, otherwise you may be looking for the problem for a long time.

You can use the following .reg file to set the CPU and IO priority of the compiler and linker to "below normal"/"low":

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\cl.exe]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\cl.exe\PerfOptions]
"CpuPriorityClass"=dword:00000005
"IoPriority"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\link.exe]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\link.exe\PerfOptions]
"CpuPriorityClass"=dword:00000005
"IoPriority"=dword:00000001
```

---

### Original Answer

I was facing the same problem and it really annoyed me. As a stop gap solution, I have created a small batch file that simply lowers the process priority of the most important build tools:

```
wmic process where name="msbuild.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
wmic process where name="cl.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
wmic process where name="link.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
```

(This is for C++ builds, if you build something else you may want to change the .exe names to whatever your main build tools are.)

Of course this only affects processes that are currently running, so you have to run it every time you start a build. The priorities of newly created sub-processes (compiler, linker, ...) are being inherited from the main MSBuild process though, so this will not only affect the currently running compiler/linker instances but the whole build.

I've added an "external tool" entry with `Command: cmd.exe` and `Arguments: /c C:\Path\To\My\LowerBuildPriority.bat` so I can start the batch file from within Visual Studio.

A more convenient solution would probably be to add a custom task to the build that alters the process priority. Since AFAIK tasks are executed from within the main MSBuild process, this should work. But I haven't gotten around to trying it yet.

Comment: Concerning the registry key, i'm unable to name a key with ending ".exe". Even as an admin.

Comment: @Scrontch No idea what the problem is, I can name keys like that just fine. It's also a common scheme in Windows to have keys named like executables.

Comment: @Scrontch I've added a snippet for a .reg file that sets the priorities for the compiler and linker. Saving as `something.reg` and then just double-clicking in Explorer should work.

Comment: Thanks, but importing the reg file doesn't work either. It's probably linked to restrictions from anti-virus software or such. I asked this on superuser.se: https://superuser.com/questions/1416288/windows10-cannot-create-a-registry-key-with-extension-exe

Comment: The script works for me (VS2017, Windows 7).  Many thanks.  +10

Comment: The script can only reduce priority of existing processes. Right at the start of the build no `link.exe` and not all `cl.exe` processes are available to apply that command. You need to call that script again during compilation and during linking.

Comment: @VisorZ Yes it can only change the priority of processes that already exist. Which is why it also changes the priority of `msbuild.exe`. Which is then inherited by the child processes that MSBuild starts. It's possible that there were changes in MSBuild since I wrote this, but back then it worked fine. I've since switched to the registry entries which are also described in this answer, so I can't say for sure if it still works.

Answer (score 13):

You can now set check box in Visual Studio 2022 under `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build And Run -> “Run build at low process priority”`. This will run all compile and link processes at "Below normal" priority

Update on Paul Groke's answer and thread linked in his answer https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/436208/limit-cpu-usage-of-visual-studio.html, because I cannot comment yet